# How to change date-format of ag grid date filter

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I use ag-grid on my Angular 5.2.11 app to display a table. In the date column, I use the default date filter agDateColumnFilter as in the documentation. The Datepicker date format is mm/dd/yyyy after using browserDatePicker: true, is there any way to change the Datepicker format

Answer (score -1):

You can use the angular datePipe to change the format https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the suggestion but can you give me an example of how do I use it. that will be useful for me.

Comment: Rahul Davane: sure you can check these links for example as well as for understanding https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-pipe-example?file=app%2Fapp.component.html , https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe